# AngularJS: line number

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, line

I will have some search result as below:
[image]

using *table*  tag and AngularJS as below:

```
      <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="customer in fndCtrl.result">
                <td>
                    1
                </td>
                <td ng-bind=":customer.CustomerNumber"></td>
                <td ng-bind=":customer.FirstName + ' ' + customer.LastName"></td>
```

how I can set the line numbe, then? I set 1 for image, above.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this -

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in fndCtrl.result">
            <td>
                {{$index+1}}
            </td>
            <td ng-bind=":customer.CustomerNumber"></td>
            <td ng-bind=":customer.FirstName + ' ' + customer.LastName"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `track by $index` to ng-repeat. The modified code is

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="customer in fndCtrl.result track by $index">
            <td>
                {{ $index + 1 }}
            </td>
            <td ng-bind=":customer.CustomerNumber"></td>
            <td ng-bind=":customer.FirstName + ' ' + customer.LastName">   </td>
```